# How to add a prototype function to an external framework?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, prototype, vis.js

I am wondering how to add my own function to an object, built by a framework. So, the framework is vis.js and I want to add the function to the DataSet object.

A dataset is generated with:

```
var myDataSet = new vis.DataSet();
```

So I figured

```
vis.DataSet.prototype.addFormattedNode = function () {...}
```

could do the trick. Sadly, Chrome Dev Tool reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DataSet is not defined
```

which is probably based on the fact, that the vis framework is not yet loaded, right? I tried adding the prototype in the dev tools (after everything is loaded) and it works. One could do that, but I am looking for the "right way" without dirty hacks :-)

Any ideas or best practices for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution

```
vis.DataSet.prototype.addFormattedNode = function () {...}
```

is should indeed just work. Of course that will only work if vis is loaded first, so you have to load stuff in the right order.

A more neat solution would be to create an extension of the prototype like this:

```
function MyDataSet (data, options) {
  vis.DataSet.call(this, data, options);
}

MyDataSet.prototype = new vis.DataSet();

MyDataSet.prototype.addFormattedNode = function () {
  // ...
};
```

Then you can use `MyDataSet` instead of `vis.DataSet`.

Comment: Works, thank you! First I had problems understanding your idea... So here is my fiddle, if anyone else needs it: http://jsfiddle.net/andrelung/c6fr4w1a/